# how to save more than one image in matlab using imwrite?

Tags: image, matlab

I have 3 parameters, each parameter give one output image, now I put one loop for the parameters and I want to have 3 output images in each loop and save it, How can I do that using imwrite ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi - welcome to StackOverflow. Can you post some code to try and show us what you've done, and what you want? See [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking good questions and [this link on MCVE's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn about minimal, complete and verifiable examples. In your case, an MCVE may be inappropriate, but some code is always nice to describe the problem! For example, show how you're currently writing one image

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand your question as clearly as expected but are you looking for something like this:

```
for i=1:3
parameter=functionGivingParamater(input_argument);%%I guess paramter is the image format
imwrite(strcat('imageNo_'+num2str(i)),parameter);
end
```